# Время в миллисекунды

Tags: android

Как в моем случае перевести время в миллисекунды? Буду рад любой помощи!

```
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        @Override
        public void TimeUpdated(int hour, int minute){      
            Context context = this;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("prediction", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorh = sharedPref.edit();
            editorh.putInt("prediction_hour", hour);
            editorh.commit();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorm = sharedPref.edit();
            editorm.putInt("prediction_min", minute);
            editorm.commit();
            timeString = (context.getResources().getString(R.string.pic)+" "+" "+(Integer.toString(hour)) + ":"+ (Integer.toString(minute)));
            TextView predictionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            predictionText.setText(timeString);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
int millises = (int) (TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes));
```